# Understanding how to handle deadlocks and their rollbacks in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, database-deadlocks

I have mainly been using `MyISAM` as a storage engine in the past and have only recently been using `InnoDB` more; and now I'm at a point where I am really starting to work with InnoDB's `locking` and `isolation levels`.

I have been reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) and one thing that concerns me is that [it states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html):

> InnoDB automatically detects transaction deadlocks and rolls back a transaction or transactions to break the deadlock.

So in other words some code that was *supposed* to run got rolled back because of a deadlock and all of a sudden your data integrity is out because said code didn't run!?

[They also state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) that:

> Normally, you must write your applications so that they are always prepared to re-issue a transaction if it gets rolled back because of a deadlock.

Trouble is it doesn't explain *how* to re-issue the queries or test if they failed because of a deadlock?

This appears to me as a significant issue that some of your code that you expect to run (queries be executed) may be rolled back and not re-issued) without you putting in extra code to avoid this. Shouldn't this be automatic?

So can someone explain to me here what the best way to handle this is or if I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some code that was supposed to run got rolled back because of a deadlock

True.  Hence your next quote about needing to rerun.  Rerunning the transaction involves something your code to go back to the `START TRANSACTION` and try again.  The re-issuing is not automatic; you do need extra code.

Be sure to check for errors, even on `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

As for what the code looks like... That depends on the API you are using.  Some already have `try/catch` syntax; some do not.

Be careful not to get in an infinite loop.  (Example, if you "loop until no error", and the error is something other than "deadlock", such as "connection lost".)

If you never have more than one user connecting at a time, deadlocks are impossible, but other errors, some transient, are possible.

As for `isolation levels`, I suggest leaving it at the default.  Only if you get into high rates of transactions and are doing special things might you need to change the level.

Comment: So if I wanted to reissue them I simply run the queries in a loop for x amount of times or until it succeeds?

Comment: Yes.  I recommend 2-3 times, then give a fatal error.  If it does not succeed on the second try, there is probably something other than a simple deadlock that is causing trouble, and you need investigate it.